# Highlighting a file in the package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, highlighting

I have developed a plugin in Eclipse which adds an option to the Package Explorer for searching a class. So the plugin searches for the class and it returns back the class path. Then it should highlight the class in the explorer.

I used this:

```
IPath iPath = new Path(path);
                        IFile file = project.getFile(iPath);

                        file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(iPath);

                        ISelection selection = new StructuredSelection(file);

                        IViewReference[] views = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences();
                        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                        .getActivePage().resetPerspective(); 
                        for(IViewReference view:views){
                            if("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer".equals(view.getId())){
                                IViewPart pExplorer = view.getView(true);
                                pExplorer.getViewSite().getSelectionProvider().setSelection(selection);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
```

However, this returns a NullPointerException in the line :
IViewReference[] views = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences();

Any hints or help would be appreciated.

---

Thanks for ur comments..now my problem is that this code does not highlight the class in the explorer for me!!

```
String path = "D:\\Programs\\eclipse\\runtime-EclipseApplication\\tessssst\\src\\testClass.java";

    IPath iPath = new Path(path);
    IFile file = project.getFile(iPath);

    file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(iPath);

    ISelection selection = new StructuredSelection(file);

    IViewReference[] views = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences();
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
    .getActivePage().resetPerspective(); 
    for(IViewReference view:views){
        if("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer".equals(view.getId())){
            IViewPart pExplorer = view.getView(true);
            pExplorer.getViewSite().getSelectionProvider().setSelection(selection);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Please guide me to correct the code! I should have a path like which i mentioned above as an input.

Comment: First find out what is `null`. To do so log/print:      `PlatformUI.getWorkbench()`,  `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()`,   `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()`

Comment: Where this code is exactly getting executed? inside any dialog box?

Comment: This part is just for highlighting the class or file in eclipse package explorer. First I search for the file, therefore i have the file path, then i want to highlight it using the path which I have!

Comment: PlatformUI.getWorkbench() is null

Answer (score 2):

Considering:

- that you mention PlatformUI.getWorkbench() is null
- the code for [`org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse%20UI/org/eclipse/ui/PlatformUI.java#L84-L95) includes:

:

```java
public static IWorkbench getWorkbench() {
    if (Workbench.getInstance() == null) {
        // app forgot to call createAndRunWorkbench beforehand
        throw new IllegalStateException(WorkbenchMessages.PlatformUI_NoWorkbench);
    }
    return Workbench.getInstance();
}
```

It could be possible that `createAndRunWorkbench()` wasn't called at the time of the invocation of your plugin (called like in [this tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/03/eclipse-tutorial-for-a-simple-desktop-application/)).

Comment: Tnx, I think that was null because my piece of code was not located in 'Execute' method!!

Comment: @OrclUser well, there is some progress at least.